# WaitAll leads to NotSupportedException for Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
WaitHandle[] _runningTaskHandles = new WaitHandle[1];
_runningTaskHandles[1] = new AutoResetEvent(false);

System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(WaitHandle[1], waitToSyncThreads);
```

Leads to `NotSupportedException` WaitAny is Ok. 
What is the discrimination?

Comment: FYI, the root cause of it being not supported (see @Ku6opr's answer) is that Windows Phone is built on the Windows CE OS.  Windows CE's implementation of the WaitForMultipleObject API does not support a `fWaitAll` parameter of anything but `FALSE`.  Basically it's not due to an issue with Silverlight or the COmpact Framework, but is a limitation of the OS itself.  See the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms915515.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> "WaitAll is present but not supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone."

source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Stupid msdn. Version Information paragraph - "Silverlight for Windows Phone
Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0"

Answer (score 2):

Just write your own, something like this is what I use:

```
    bool MyWaitAll(WaitHandle [] waitHandleArray, int timeout)
    {
        int wait = 1000;
        int startTick = Environment.TickCount;
        foreach (WaitHandle wh in waitHandleArray)
        {
            while(!wh.WaitOne(wait))
            {
                if((Environment.TickCount - startTick) > timeout)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on MSDN is mentioning that [WaitAll(WaitHandle[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is not supported on Windows Phone 7.

Although it's not very clear (At the end of the page Windows phone is still listed in the supported platforms)